# Lucene fuzzy search on a phrase (FuzzyQuery + SpanQuery)

Tags: lucene, fuzzy-search

I am looking for a way of coding the lucene fuzzy query that searches all the documents, which are relevant to an exact phrase. If I search "mosa employee appreciata", a document contains "most employees appreciate" will be returned as the result.

I tried to use:

```
FuzzyQeury = new FuzzyQuery(new Term("contents","mosa employee appreicata"))
```

Unfortunately, it empirically doesn't work. The FuzzyQuery employs the editor distance, theoretically, "mosa employee appreciata" should be matched with "most employees appreciate" provide the appropriate distance is given. It seems a bit odd.

Any clues? Thank you.

Comment: Additional details are needed: How did you index the contents field? What Analyzer are you using? Did you try a closer search (start with the exact phrase, then change a single character,...)? How much latitude do you give in the query parameters? What exactly did you get?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer from femtoRgon is great! Thank you.

There is another way to solve this problem.

```
//declare a mutilphrasequery
MultiPhraseQuery childrenInOrder = new MultiPhraseQuery();

//user fuzzytermenum to enumerate your query string
FuzzyTermEnum fuzzyEnumeratedTerms1 = new FuzzyTermEnum(reader, new Term(searchField,"mosa"));
FuzzyTermEnum fuzzyEnumeratedTerms2 = new FuzzyTermEnum(reader, new Term(searchField,"employee"));
FuzzyTermEnum fuzzyEnumeratedTerms3 = new FuzzyTermEnum(reader, new Term(searchField,"appreicata"));

//this basically pull out the possbile terms from the index             
Term termHolder1 = fuzzyEnumeratedTerms1.term();
Term termHolder2 = fuzzyEnumeratedTerms2.term();
Term termHolder3 = fuzzyEnumeratedTerms3.term();

//put the possible terms into multiphrasequery
if (termHolder1==null){
    childrenInOrder.add(new Term(searchField,"mosa"));
}else{
    childrenInOrder.add(fuzzyEnumeratedTerms1.term());
}

if (termHolder2==null){
    childrenInOrder.add(new Term(searchField,"employee"));
}else{
    childrenInOrder.add(fuzzyEnumeratedTerms2.term());
}

if (termHolder3==null){
    childrenInOrder.add(new Term(searchField,"appreicata"));
}else{
    childrenInOrder.add(fuzzyEnumeratedTerms3.term());
}


//close it - it is important to close it
fuzzyEnumeratedTerms1.close();
fuzzyEnumeratedTerms2.close();
fuzzyEnumeratedTerms3.close();
```

Comment: what version of lucene have you used? I can;t seem to find FuzzyTermEnum api for 4.6. in 4.6 there's only FuzzyTermsEnum with different constructor

Comment: IMHO this doesn't actually do what you intended. Maybe for your simple example but not for more complex documents with more text. Because the FuzzyTermEnum doesn't give the right terms fromout larger documents in the index...

Answer (score 16):

There are two likely problems here.  First:  I'm guessing the "contents" field is being analyzed such that "most employees apreciate" is not a term, but rather three terms.  Defining as a single term is not appropriate in this case.

However, even if the content listed is a single term, a second likely problem we have is that there is too much distance between the terms to get a match.  The Damerau-Levenshtein distance between `mosa employee appreicata` and `most employees appreciate` is 4 (the approximate distance, incidentally, between my average first shot at spelling 
"Damerau-Levenshtein" and the correct spelling).  Fuzzy Query, as of 4.0, handles edit distances of no more than 2, due to performance constraints, and the assumption that larger distances are usually not particularly relevant.

If you need to perform a phrase query with fuzzy terms, you should look into either [`MultiPhraseQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/MultiPhraseQuery.html), or combine a set of [`SpanQueries`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/SpanQuery.html) (especially `SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper` and `SpanNearQuery`) to meet your needs.

```
SpanQuery[] clauses = new SpanQuery[3];
clauses[0] = new SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper(new FuzzyQuery(new Term("contents", "mosa")));
clauses[1] = new SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper(new FuzzyQuery(new Term("contents", "employee")));
clauses[2] = new SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper(new FuzzyQuery(new Term("contents", "appreicata")));
SpanNearQuery query = new SpanNearQuery(clauses, 0, true)
```

And since none of the individual terms have an edit distance greater than 2, this should be more effective.

Comment: Can I achieve the same thing with Lucene Query Language?

Comment: @isah - You mean with the standard QueryParser?  *No*, you can not.  The [ComplexPhrase parser](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/complexPhrase/ComplexPhraseQueryParser.html) could...

Comment: Yes I have done it with ComplexQueryParser just after asking you, thanks though.

Comment: @femtoRgon could you exemplify how you would achieve the same with the ComplexPhrase parser?

Comment: @pelican_george - Just pass it a query like:  `"\"mosa~ employee~ appreicata~\""`

Comment: @femtoRgon The complex phrase parser only handles phrase slop and not terms right? In this case if he would not get any hits for "mosa~ appreicata~ mosa~"  If order is not important which approach would you advise?

Comment: @pelican_george - No, handles fuzzy terms and such as well as phrase slop, that's the whole point.  Regarding order, [see the docs](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/complexPhrase/ComplexPhraseQueryParser.html#setInOrder-boolean-).  Or take the approach provided in my *answer*, either way.

Comment: @femtoRgon ah I see. I was using a C# ported version of the parser taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28094280/complex-phrases-and-or-complexphrasequeryparser-in-lucene-net/28111214#28111214 no matter what slop I set, I only get in order matches.

Comment: I assume that using `MultiPhraseQuery` involves expanding out a FuzzyQuery and inserting each term into a position in the MultiPhraseQuery?  Could get big if there are a lot of matching terms.

Answer (score 1):

`ComplexPhraseQueryParser` handles fuzzy searching on phrase words - i.e., specify the words that should be fuzzy searched and those that should not. Works as follows

```
Query query = new ComplexPhraseQueryParser("content", analyzer)
                    .parse("some test~ query~ blah blah");
```

Seems to work nicely. Not sure about performance, however but seems to work well on small data sets.

Answer (score 0):

I had some (very small) millage with the following:

```
String[] searchTerms = searchString.split(" ");
FuzzyLikeThisQuery fltw = new FuzzyLikeThisQuery(searchTerms.length, new StandardAnalyzer());
Arrays.stream(searchTerms)
    .forEach(term -> fltq.addTerms(term, FIELD, SIMILARITY_IN_EDITS, PREFIX_LENGTH);
```

This query matches far too distant strings with the index. String that don't match are ones where each of the terms are distant by more than 2 edits from the terms used in the indexed content.

### Please use at your own peril.