# Complex Phrases and/or ComplexPhraseQueryParser in Lucene.NET

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I am trying to search for fairly complex queries with Lucene.Net like

> "inject* needle*" OR "point* thingy"~2

So basically I need wildcards in regular as well as proximity phrases. However, the basic Lucene.Net *QueryParser* gets rid of these wildcards.

I understand that *ComplexPhraseQueryParser* would work for that, unfortunately this is not included in Lucene.Net.

Is there any way of constructing queries like this in Lucene.Net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up by actually porting the *ComplexPhraseQueryParser* from Java to C#. It was a lot easier than expected and was a good excercise for learning C# a bit better.

I have provided the code below in case it is helpfull to anyone else. Please note that it is still very Java-like Code as I am a lot more familiar with Java than I am with C# ;-)

```
/**
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 * contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 * this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 * The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 * (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 * the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

// Ported to C# from Java source at http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-misc/3.0.3/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/complexPhrase/ComplexPhraseQueryParser.java


using Lucene.Net.Analysis;
using Lucene.Net.Index;

using Lucene.Net.QueryParsers;
using Lucene.Net.Search;
using Lucene.Net.Search.Spans;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Version = Lucene.Net.Util.Version;

public class ComplexPhraseQueryParser : QueryParser
{
    private List<ComplexPhraseQuery> complexPhrases = null;

    private Boolean isPass2ResolvingPhrases;

    private ComplexPhraseQuery currentPhraseQuery = null;

    public ComplexPhraseQueryParser(Version matchVersion, String f, Analyzer a) : base(matchVersion, f, a) { }



    protected override Query GetFieldQuery(String field, String queryText, int slop)
    {
        ComplexPhraseQuery cpq = new ComplexPhraseQuery(field, queryText, slop);
        complexPhrases.Add(cpq); // add to list of phrases to be parsed once
        // we
        // are through with this pass
        return cpq;
    }


    public override Query Parse(String query)
    {
        if (isPass2ResolvingPhrases)
        {
            RewriteMethod oldMethod = MultiTermRewriteMethod;
            try
            {
                // Temporarily force BooleanQuery rewrite so that Parser will
                // generate visible
                // collection of terms which we can convert into SpanQueries.
                // ConstantScoreRewrite mode produces an
                // opaque ConstantScoreQuery object which cannot be interrogated for
                // terms in the same way a BooleanQuery can.
                // QueryParser is not guaranteed threadsafe anyway so this temporary
                // state change should not
                // present an issue
                MultiTermRewriteMethod = MultiTermQuery.SCORING_BOOLEAN_QUERY_REWRITE;
                return base.Parse(query);
            }
            finally
            {
                MultiTermRewriteMethod = oldMethod;
            }
        }

        // First pass - parse the top-level query recording any PhraseQuerys
        // which will need to be resolved
        complexPhrases = new List<ComplexPhraseQuery>();
        Query q = base.Parse(query);

        // Perform second pass, using this QueryParser to parse any nested
        // PhraseQueries with different
        // set of syntax restrictions (i.e. all fields must be same)
        isPass2ResolvingPhrases = true;
        try
        {
            using (IEnumerator<ComplexPhraseQuery> enumerator = complexPhrases.GetEnumerator())
            {
                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    currentPhraseQuery = enumerator.Current;
                    currentPhraseQuery.ParsePhraseElements(this);
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            isPass2ResolvingPhrases = false;
        }
        return q;
    }

    // There is No "getTermQuery throws ParseException" method to override so
    // unfortunately need
    // to throw a runtime exception here if a term for another field is embedded
    // in phrase query
    protected override Query NewTermQuery(Term term)
    {
        if (isPass2ResolvingPhrases)
        {
            try
            {
                CheckPhraseClauseIsForSameField(term.Field);
            }
            catch (ParseException pe)
            {
                throw new SystemException("Error parsing complex phrase", pe);
            }
        }
        return base.NewTermQuery(term);
    }

    // Helper method used to report on any clauses that appear in query syntax
    private void CheckPhraseClauseIsForSameField(String field)
    {
        if (!field.Equals(currentPhraseQuery.Field))
        {
            throw new ParseException("Cannot have clause for field \"" + field
                + "\" nested in phrase " + " for field \"" + currentPhraseQuery.Field
                + "\"");
        }
    }

    protected override Query GetWildcardQuery(String field, String termStr)
    {
        if (isPass2ResolvingPhrases)
        {
            CheckPhraseClauseIsForSameField(field);
        }
        return base.GetWildcardQuery(field, termStr);
    }

    protected override Query GetRangeQuery(String field, String part1, String part2, Boolean inclusive)
    {
        if (isPass2ResolvingPhrases)
        {
            CheckPhraseClauseIsForSameField(field);
        }
        return base.GetRangeQuery(field, part1, part2, inclusive);
    }

    protected override Query NewRangeQuery(String field, String part1, String part2,
        Boolean inclusive)
    {
        if (isPass2ResolvingPhrases)
        {
            // Must use old-style RangeQuery in order to produce a BooleanQuery
            // that can be turned into SpanOr clause
            TermRangeQuery rangeQuery = new TermRangeQuery(field, part1, part2, inclusive, inclusive, RangeCollator);
            rangeQuery.RewriteMethod = MultiTermQuery.SCORING_BOOLEAN_QUERY_REWRITE;
            return rangeQuery;
        }
        return base.NewRangeQuery(field, part1, part2, inclusive);
    }


    protected Query GetFuzzyQuery(String field, String termStr, float minSimilarity)
    {
        if (isPass2ResolvingPhrases)
        {
            CheckPhraseClauseIsForSameField(field);
        }
        return base.GetFuzzyQuery(field, termStr, minSimilarity);
    }

    /*
     * Used to handle the query content in between quotes and produced Span-based
     * interpretations of the clauses.
     */
    class ComplexPhraseQuery : Query
    {

        public string Field { get; set; }

        public string PhrasedQueryStringContents { get; set; }

        public int SlopFactor { get; set; }

        private Query Contents;

        public ComplexPhraseQuery(string Field, string PhrasedQueryStringContents, int SlopFactor)
            : base()
        {
            this.Field = Field;
            this.PhrasedQueryStringContents = PhrasedQueryStringContents;
            this.SlopFactor = SlopFactor;
        }

        // Called by ComplexPhraseQueryParser for each phrase after the main
        // parse
        // thread is through
        public void ParsePhraseElements(QueryParser qp)
        {
            // TODO ensure that field-sensitivity is preserved ie the query
            // string below is parsed as
            // field+":("+phrasedQueryStringContents+")"
            // but this will need code in rewrite to unwrap the first layer of
            // boolean query
            Contents = qp.Parse(PhrasedQueryStringContents);
        }

        public override Query Rewrite(IndexReader reader)
        {
            // ArrayList spanClauses = new ArrayList();
            if (Contents is TermQuery)
            {
                return Contents;
            }

            // Build a sequence of Span clauses arranged in a SpanNear - child
            // clauses can be complex
            // Booleans e.g. nots and ors etc
            int numNegatives = 0;
            if (!(Contents is BooleanQuery))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Unknown query type \""
                    + Contents.GetType()
                    + "\" found in phrase query string \"" + PhrasedQueryStringContents
                    + "\"");
            }
            BooleanQuery bq = (BooleanQuery)Contents;
            BooleanClause[] bclauses = bq.GetClauses();
            SpanQuery[] allSpanClauses = new SpanQuery[bclauses.Length];
            // For all clauses e.g. one* two~
            for (int i = 0; i < bclauses.Length; i++)
            {
                // HashSet bclauseterms=new HashSet();
                Query qc = bclauses[i].Query;
                // Rewrite this clause e.g one* becomes (one OR onerous)
                qc = qc.Rewrite(reader);
                if (bclauses[i].Occur.Equals(Occur.MUST_NOT))
                {
                    numNegatives++;
                }

                if (qc is BooleanQuery)
                {
                    List<SpanQuery> sc = new List<SpanQuery>();
                    AddComplexPhraseClause(sc, (BooleanQuery)qc);
                    if (sc.Count > 0)
                    {
                        allSpanClauses[i] = sc[0];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Insert fake term e.g. phrase query was for "Fred Smithe*" and
                        // there were no "Smithe*" terms - need to
                        // prevent match on just "Fred".
                        allSpanClauses[i] = new SpanTermQuery(new Term(Field,
                            "Dummy clause because no terms found - must match nothing"));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (qc is TermQuery)
                    {
                        TermQuery tq = (TermQuery)qc;
                        allSpanClauses[i] = new SpanTermQuery(tq.Term);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException("Unknown query type \""
                            + qc.GetType()
                            + "\" found in phrase query string \""
                            + PhrasedQueryStringContents + "\"");
                    }

                }
            }
            if (numNegatives == 0)
            {
                // The simple case - no negative elements in phrase
                return new SpanNearQuery(allSpanClauses, SlopFactor, true);
            }
            // Complex case - we have mixed positives and negatives in the
            // sequence.
            // Need to return a SpanNotQuery
            List<SpanQuery> positiveClauses = new List<SpanQuery>();
            for (int j = 0; j < allSpanClauses.Length; j++)
            {
                if (!bclauses[j].Occur.Equals(Occur.MUST_NOT))
                {
                    positiveClauses.Add(allSpanClauses[j]);
                }
            }

            //SpanQuery[] includeClauses = positiveClauses.ToArray(new SpanQuery[positiveClauses.Count]);
            SpanQuery[] includeClauses = positiveClauses.ToArray();

            SpanQuery include = null;
            if (includeClauses.Length == 1)
            {
                include = includeClauses[0]; // only one positive clause
            }
            else
            {
                // need to increase slop factor based on gaps introduced by
                // negatives
                include = new SpanNearQuery(includeClauses, SlopFactor + numNegatives,
                    true);
            }
            // Use sequence of positive and negative values as the exclude.
            SpanNearQuery exclude = new SpanNearQuery(allSpanClauses, SlopFactor,
                true);
            SpanNotQuery snot = new SpanNotQuery(include, exclude);
            return snot;
        }

        private void AddComplexPhraseClause(List<SpanQuery> spanClauses, BooleanQuery qc)
        {
            List<SpanQuery> ors = new List<SpanQuery>();
            List<SpanQuery> nots = new List<SpanQuery>();
            BooleanClause[] bclauses = qc.GetClauses();

            // For all clauses e.g. one* two~
            for (int i = 0; i < bclauses.Length; i++)
            {
                Query childQuery = bclauses[i].Query;

                // select the list to which we will add these options
                List<SpanQuery> chosenList = ors;
                if (bclauses[i].Occur == Occur.MUST_NOT)
                {
                    chosenList = nots;
                }

                if (childQuery is TermQuery)
                {
                    TermQuery tq = (TermQuery)childQuery;
                    SpanTermQuery stq = new SpanTermQuery(tq.Term);
                    stq.Boost = tq.Boost;
                    chosenList.Add(stq);
                }
                else if (childQuery is BooleanQuery)
                {
                    BooleanQuery cbq = (BooleanQuery)childQuery;
                    AddComplexPhraseClause(chosenList, cbq);
                }
                else
                {
                    // TODO alternatively could call extract terms here?
                    throw new ArgumentException("Unknown query type:"
                        + childQuery.GetType());
                }
            }
            if (ors.Count == 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            SpanOrQuery soq = new SpanOrQuery(ors.ToArray());
            if (nots.Count == 0)
            {
                spanClauses.Add(soq);
            }
            else
            {
                SpanOrQuery snqs = new SpanOrQuery(nots.ToArray());
                SpanNotQuery snq = new SpanNotQuery(soq, snqs);
                spanClauses.Add(snq);
            }
        }


        public override String ToString(String field)
        {
            return "\"" + PhrasedQueryStringContents + "\"";
        }


        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            const int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((Field == null) ? 0 : Field.GetHashCode());
            result = prime
                * result
                + ((PhrasedQueryStringContents == null) ? 0
                    : PhrasedQueryStringContents.GetHashCode());
            result = prime * result + SlopFactor;
            return result;
        }

        public override Boolean Equals(Object obj)
        {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (GetType() != obj.GetType())
                return false;
            ComplexPhraseQuery other = (ComplexPhraseQuery)obj;
            if (Field == null)
            {
                if (other.Field != null)
                    return false;
            }
            else if (!Field.Equals(other.Field))
                return false;
            if (PhrasedQueryStringContents == null)
            {
                if (other.PhrasedQueryStringContents != null)
                    return false;
            }
            else if (!PhrasedQueryStringContents
              .Equals(other.PhrasedQueryStringContents))
                return false;
            if (SlopFactor != other.SlopFactor)
                return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get the Slop to work for fuzzy terms? I'm using your ported version from Java to C# and I only get matches for fuzzy terms in order. ex: "som~  dumm~ tex~" with slop 2 will only match "some dummy text" and not "some text dummy". (standardanalyzer)

Comment: I haven't worked on this for over a year but I think I figured out what causes your problem. The slop should work but the 'inorder' property of the SpanNearQuery is hardcoded to true in my code. That is why your query does not match "some text dummy" but it should match something like "some interesting dummy text" with up to 2 words inbetween the three terms in your query.
Hope this helps